# Android Time Tracker

Tags: android, timer

I have found several tutorials for making a timer/stopwatch in Android. Despite these efforts I am unable to get them to work. The application should include 10 timers that tracks time spend on a certain task. If one has spend an x amount of time that is tracked by the timer, this should be added to the total amount of time spend on this task.

If have looked at 
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html
http://steve.odyfamily.com/?p=12 
and a few other Google hits ofcourse.

What method would be the best to use in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [System.nanoTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29) method. It's preferred solution to measure elapsed time.